signalfd with multithreaded epoll instances
Let's say a web server utilizes SO_REUSEPORT for improved load distribution in a multi-threaded server, i.e. each thread opens its own listening socket (on the same port) whose file descriptor is added to each thread's epoll instance.
epoll can monitor a specific file descriptor to accept signals created by signalfd().
Upon receiving a signal each thread's epoll_wait will return an event which we'd naturally want to read from. However, an occurrence of a signal can only be read once, thus only one thread will get information about the signal (others will be blocked on read unless specified otherwise).
Would you say there is a simple solution to it or this renders signalfd practically unusable in this particular scenario?
Thanks.

A possible solution would consist to create an additional file descriptor for each thread on which they wait (through epoll()). To make this, use eventfd(). Then, once a thread receives the signal, it can broadcast an event on all the event file descriptors (simple write() call) to warn the other threads.
